# Is there a cognitive bias that makes people consider information coming from someone they don't like as more likely to be wrong?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, bias

Frequently I noticed this happening with people. When A dislikes B, A tends to think B is wrong all the time. And it seems to be persistent, even when B is proven correct multiple times, it doesn't change A's opinion about B. Conversely, when A likes B, A is more likely to think B is not wrong.

Comment: Related: [What is the most accurate name for the effect where people find excuses for flaws by leaders?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/21933/7001)

Comment: I think these are called the "Halo effect" and the "Horn effect" for positive and negative biases respectively.